# How to plot arccos and sqrt together

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot the function y=4/pi * arccos(x/4) and 2-sqrt(x) (see image).  This comes from AP Central.  I am having trouble figuring out the proper axes to use to show both images.  I can plot the square root function without trouble, but trying to add an inverse trig function is messing with me.

Any help would be appreciated. I tried to Google it, without much luck.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}




\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}
\newcommand*{\dprime}{^{\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\newcommand*{\trprime}{^{\prime\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
% Edit these as appropriate
\newcommand\course{AP Calculus AB}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 35pt
\lhead{Mark Sparks}
\chead{\textbf{Topic 8.5 Finding the Area Between Curves \\ Expressed as Functions of \(x\) }}
\rhead{\course \\ \today}
\lfoot{Mr. Bennett}
\cfoot{Flint Hill Upper School}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}
\headsep 1.5em
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 



\begin{document}


\subsection*{AP Test Preparation}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
                \begin{axis}[thick,
                        scale only axis,
                    grid=major,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        inner axis line style={-Triangle},
                        ytick={-1,0,...,3},
                        xtick={-1,0,...,5},
                        ymin=-1,
                        ymax=3,
                        xmin=-1,
                        xmax=5,
                    ]
                    \addplot[thick,samples=1000,domain=0:4]{2-sqrt(x)};
                    \addplot[thick,samples=1000,domain=0:4]{1.27324*acos(x/4)
                
                    \node at (2,1){\(R\)};  
                    
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}


                        

\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Let \(R\) be the region in the first quadrant bounded above by the graph of \(y=\dfrac{4}{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{4}\right)\) and below by the graph of \(y=2-\sqrt{x}\), as shown in the figure above.  What is the area of the region?
    
    A. \(\dfrac{4}{3}\) \\
    
    B. \(\dfrac{16}{\pi}+\dfrac{8}{3}\) \\
    
    C. \(\dfrac{16}{\pi}-\dfrac{8}{3}\) \\
    
    D. \(\dfrac{16}{3}\) \\
    
        \rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
    
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I your code there is 2 mistakes.

First, in `\addplot[thick,samples=1000,domain=0:4]{1.27324*acos(x/4)` you missed the closed brace and the semi-column `};`.

Second, the `acos` function return result in degree. So acos(0) return 90. If you would result in radian, multiply it by pi/180. As you would (4/pi) * acos(x), and (pi/180) * (4/pi) is 1/45 (approx 0.02222), so, just replace

`\addplot[thick,samples=1000,domain=0:4]{1.27324*acos(x/4)`

by

`\addplot[thick,samples=1000,domain=0:4]{0.02222*acos(x/4)};`

and you obtain:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for you help.